# How is SELinux loaded on boot?

Tags: selinux

I understand that a configuration file is in:

```
/etc/selinux/config
```

But how is it processed at boot? How does SELinux start, is it a daemon? Which startup script starts SELinux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux policy is loaded by init in early boot. Init checks that SELinux is enabeld, after which it loads the policy and re-executes itself in correct security context.

Sources: [RHEL4 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/SELinux_Guide/rhlcommon-section-0016.html), [Ubuntu Hardy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardySELinux#line-58), [systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/ad16158c10dfc3258831a9ff2f1a988214f51653/src/core/main.c#L2218)

Comment: Is there a syscall can be used by userspace to load selinux policy? And it's usually called by init?

Comment: systemd [seems](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/ad16158c10dfc3258831a9ff2f1a988214f51653/src/core/selinux-setup.c#L63) to use `selinux_init_load_policy` provided in [SELinux C API](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-security_load_policy/)

Comment: So init is responsible for selinux policy (probably reads the file in /etc/selinux/config) . There is no additional init scripts related with selinux, and  no additional daemon. Right ? Thx!

Comment: Exactly, it is explained in detail in RHEL4 link.